# Creating Common TextBox for all input type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

As I am new to react JS, I need support in creating a common text box for all input type.
Moreover, I have developed the textbox, but I need to reveal password functionality when the type is password.
However, currently, my reveal password element disappears when I click on it for the first time.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const TextBox=(props)=> {
const [type, setType] = useState('text');
const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState('Text');
const [passValue, setPassValue] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    setType(props.type);
    setPlaceholder(props.placeholder);
}, []);

const handleChange=(e)=>{
    setPassValue(e.target.value);
}

const showHide=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setType(type === 'input' ? 'password' : 'input') 
}

return (
    <div>
    <h1>{type}:{placeholder}</h1>
    <input type={type} placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleChange}></input>
    {(type==='password', type=== 'input') && 
        <div>
            <p>This is Password</p>
                <span onClick={showHide}>{type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</span>
        </div>
    }
    {(type==='text')&&<p>This is Text</p>}
    {(type==='email')&&<p>This is an Email</p>}
    </div>
);
}
export default TextBox;
```

My Props are getting fetched through the below Code:

```
<TextBox type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password"/>
```

How can I display Show/Hide in the input text at left side of it, keeping the above code?

```
<input class='container textContainer' type={type} placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleChange} /> 
{(type==='password' || type=== 'input') && 
<span onClick={showHide}> 
    {type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} 
</span> }
```

Comment: How can I move placeholder at top when clicked on textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your password condition to below code

```
  {(type==='password' || type=== 'input') && 
  <div>
    <p>This is Password</p>
      <span onClick={showHide}>
        {type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
      </span>
  </div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the problem with your condition.

```
...
{(type==='password', type=== 'input') && 
...
```

It should be

```
...
{(type==='password' || type=== 'input') && 
...
```

Here is the working demo for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gy8fti

Comment: How can I display Show/Hide in the input text at left side of it, keeping the above code? 

<input class='container textContainer' type={type} placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleChange} /> {(type==='password' || type=== 'input') && <span onClick={showHide}> {type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} </span> }

Comment: How can I move placeholder at top when clicked on textbox?

Comment: For that, you have to use MATERIAL-UI theme. https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/

Answer (score 0):

The way that you're dealing with the conditions on when to show elements was crashing the app.

Also, you might want to reconsider using that `useEffect` and allow the component to be more controlled. You don't need to save the `type` and `placeholder` props to state, and removing it simplifies your code a little.

```
function TextBox({ type, placeholder }) {

  const [ value, setValue ] = useState('');
  const [ visible, setVisible ] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
  const showhide = () => setVisible(visible => !visible);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{type}:{placeholder}</h1>
      <input
        value={value}
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {type === 'password' && (
        <div>
          <p>This is Password <button onClick={showhide}>Show/Hide</button></p>
          {visible && <span>{value}</span>}
        </div>
      )}
      {type==='text' && <p>This is Text</p>}
      {type==='email' && <p>This is an Email</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-dream-5rhcu)

Comment: How can I display Show/Hide in the input text at left side of it, keeping the above code?

    <input class='container textContainer' type={type} placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleChange} />
    {(type==='password' || type=== 'input') && <span onClick={showHide}> {type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
    </span>
      }

Comment: How can I move placeholder at top when clicked on textbox?